# How do i reload a div every 20 seconds?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

So i have this script:

```
<script id="_wauwgs">var _wau = _wau || []; _wau.push(["small", "p00ystfryeuc", "wgs"]);
    (function() {var s=document.createElement("script"); s.async=true;
    s.src="http://widgets.amung.us/small.js";
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
})();</script>
```

And i would like to reload it every 20 or 30 seconds. I tried using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refresh() {
    document.getElementById('online').src = document.getElementById('online').src;
    }
    window.setInterval("refresh()",30000);
</script>
```

With the script in `<div id="online"></div>` but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe it is better to recall functions from the script than to reload the script entirely? Note, that caching may also prevent full reload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
setInterval(function(){
   $("#online").attr('src', 'http://widgets.amung.us/small.js', 3000 /*or 2000*/);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to refresh a script is to insert it again.

```
var script = $('#online').html();
        function reloadScript() {
            $time = 500;
            $('#online').html('');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#online').html(script);
                reloadScript();
            }, $time);
        }
        reloadScript();
```

Comment: You are adding the same content again. What is the use of reload here?